# IntelliJ 2021.1 - How to increase the number of "recent" run configurations?

Tags: intellij-idea

In previous versions of IntelliJ IDEA, I'd always go into the "run configuration template settings" area and increase the number of run configurations from `5` to `15`.

How do I do that with IDEA 2021.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of `2021.3.2`, IntelliJ has re-introduced a UI mechanism for configuring the number of "temporary configurations".

File | Settings | Advanced Settings | Temporary Run/Debug configurations limit:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: this answer no longer works as of `2021.3.2` (may have happened on previous versions, this is when I noticed it).

The registry entry will still be there if you edited it previously, but will no longer work to extend the list of run configurations.

---

I can't see how to do it using the UI, but it can be done via the Idea "Registry".

Open the Maintenance dialog be pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`/` and select the "Registry".

Set the value for `run.anything.context.recent.directory.number` to whatever you want.

**Edit**: also consider changing `temporary.configurations.limit`.

[image: registry dialog with recent entry item selected]